# Find all Real polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

"Find all real polynomials for which $f(2) = 3, f(3) = 5$ and $f(5) = 2$."

Well my first thought was, since we have three points i can determine a polynomial of second degree such that it satisfies all points.

But doing this i got: $f(x) = -7/6x^2 + 47/6x -8$.
Then i thought, well this $f$ could be a sum of two polynomials 
$f(x) = q(x) +r(x)$, where $r(x)=0$ for $x=2, x=3, x=5$. So $f$ would be $f(x)=-7/6x^2 + 47/6x -8 +r(x)$.

Then i got another thought. Well maybe there is some polynomial in $Z_m[x]$
that satisfies $$f(2)=3, f(3)=5, f(5)=2$$
I found in $Z_5[x]$ that $Z_5[x] = [3]x^2 + [2]x + [2]$. Has the the proporties:
$Z_5[2] = [18] = [3], Z_5[3] = [35] = [5] = [0], Z_5[5] = [87] = [2].$

I have just been fooling around abit. I dont know how to procced. I just wrote down my thoughts.

Comment: I must confess I don't get which is your precise question. Are you asking if your procedure is right? Or you're looking for a tip...

Comment: I like your first thought.  Add $(x-2)^n (x-3)^m (x-5)^p$ where $n,m$ and $p$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: @PaulSundheim I think there is no need for the exponents

Comment: @Elaqqad The OP asked for "all real polynomials".  The exponents are necessary.

Comment: @PaulSundheim I mean all polynomials solution to the problem can be written as $f(x)+(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)Q(x)$ with $Q$ any another polynomial and there is no need for exponent in this expressions because $Q$ may contain other factors of this form

Comment: @Elaqqad Thank you for the correction.  You are right.

Comment: Im looking for a tip.

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts came up with:$$f(x)=(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)g(x)+(x-3)(x-5)-5(x-2)(x-5)/2+(x-2)(x-3)/3$$where $g(x)$ can be **any** polynomial as the term involving it will become zero at $f(2),f(3),f(5)$.

The second term ensures $f(2)=3$

The thrid term ensures $f(3)=5$

The fourth term ensures $f(5)=2$

**NOTE:** This reduces down to what you found above as:$$(x-3)(x-5)-5(x-2)(x-5)/2+(x-2)(x-3)/3=-\frac{7x^2}{6}+\frac{47x}{6}-8$$$$\therefore f(x)=(x-2)(x-3)(x-5)g(x)-\frac{7x^2}{6}+\frac{47x}{6}-8$$

Comment: I see! Well I understand what you have done. But do you think that this is the whole solution? Since this is a class in abstract algebra, this seems to easy?

Comment: I believe this covers all real polynomials that satisfy the conditions of the question

Comment: Missing is an argument of the following kind: When $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two solutions of the problem then $f_1-f_2$ has to be zero at $x\in\{2,3,5\}$. Therefore $f_1(x)-f_2(x)=(x-2)(x-3)(x-5) g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$.